# How to use boost asio steady timer expiry to get the execute timepoint

Tags: c++, boost, timer, asio

I want to get the time point when the boost asio steady timer fires.
The documentation says "expiry Get the timer's expiry time as an absolute time".
I do not understand what is the absolute time. I do not understand the result off expiry. Demo: ([on wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/G7Np0XGEqEAFcrX3))

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main ()
{
  using namespace boost::asio;
  io_service io;
  auto timer = steady_timer (io);
  using namespace std::chrono_literals;
  using namespace std::chrono;
  std::cout << "before timer set" << std::endl;
  std::cout << duration_cast<seconds> (timer.expiry ().time_since_epoch ()).count () << " seconds" << std::endl;
  timer.expires_after (10s);
  std::cout << "after timer set" << std::endl;
  std::cout << duration_cast<seconds> (timer.expiry ().time_since_epoch ()).count () << " seconds" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "current time using system_clock::now ()" << std::endl;
  std::cout << duration_cast<seconds> (system_clock::now ().time_since_epoch ()).count () << " seconds" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
before timer set
0 seconds
after timer set
21652309 seconds
current time using system_clock::now ()
1626725470 seconds
```

My question is how to get the time when the timer fires with boost asio steady timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are comparing apples to oranges. `system_clock` and `steady_clock` do not share the same epoch. In other words, they represent time from different reference points.

The fact that you had to go through `time_since_epoch()` in order to compare them is a big indicator that you really shouldn't be comparing them in the first place.

If you replace your last printout to use `steady_clock::now()`, the output becomes:

```
before timer set
0 seconds
after timer set
21656958 seconds
current time using system_clock::now ()
21656948 seconds
```

With the expected difference of 10 seconds.

> My question is how to get the time when the timer fires with boost asio steady timer?

You can get the remaining time on the timer by getting the difference between `expiry()` and the current time, which is simply the `-` operator as long as both time points are relative to the same epoch:

```
cout << duration_cast<seconds>(timer.expiry() - steady_clock::now()).count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
```

Comment: I'd write that as `(timer.expiry() - steady_clock::now()) / 1.0s` (or `1s` for integer division). None of this is absolute timestamps, though.

Comment: If you want to send the time point from one system to another you may use boost::asio::system_timer instead of boost::asio::steady_timer because boost::asio::steady_timer is not based on a fixed time point like boost::asio::system_timer (time 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970)